# Display wordpress posts in different columns

Tags: php, wordpress

I try to figure out to display the wordpress posts in my blog page in different columns.
Example : First two posts in two rows, remaining posts in two columns one by one same as attached.

How can i display posts same as attached?

Thanks in Advance!!

[image]

And here is my code.

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
                <?php
                $news_args = array(
                    'cat' => 3,
                    'paged' => get_query_var('paged'),
                    'posts_per_page' => 4,
                    'orderby' => 'post_date',
                    'order' => 'DESC',
                );
                $news_query = new WP_Query($news_args);
                if ($news_query->have_posts()) :
                while ($news_query->have_posts()) : $news_query->the_post();
                ?>

                                <h3><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
                                    <p><span><?php the_time('F j, Y'); ?>
                                    </span>
                                    <span><?php echo "By: ".get_the_author(); ?>
                                    </span>
                                    <span>
                                    <?php
                                    $commentcount = comments_number('0', '1', '%');
                                    $fulltitle = $title . ' (' . $commentcount . ' comments)';
                                    ?>Comments<?php wp_count_comments( $post_id ); ?> 
                                    </span></p>

                                <figure class="fig_rel1">
                                <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
                                </figure>
                                <p>
                                <?php
                                $content = get_the_content('',FALSE,'');
                                $content = apply_filters('the_content', $content);
                                $content = str_replace(']]>', ']]>', $content);
                                echo substr($content,0,300).'<a href="'. get_permalink($post->ID) .'">Read More &raquo; </a>';
                                ?>
                                </p>

                <?php
                endwhile;
                previous_posts_link('prev', $news_query->max_num_pages);
                echo ' &mdash; ';
                next_posts_link('next', $news_query->max_num_pages);
                endif;
                ?>

                </div>
                </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: So, what is the question?

Comment: How can i display same as attached?

Comment: So, what have you tried in order to get the above design?

Comment: I got all the posts one after one

Comment: try here asking once : http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Do i get the solution here!!

Comment: @nsdlfefinedieicbe, When i try to post my question there, it is showing "You can only post once every 40 minutes."

Comment: okay after 40 minutes you can post as you dont have 125 reputation.

Comment: Thanks!!  i will post my question there after 40 mins..  If you have any idea, please let me know...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can help you.

```
$news_args = array(
    'cat' => 3,
    'paged' => get_query_var('paged'),
    'posts_per_page' => 4,
    'orderby' => 'post_date',
    'order' => 'DESC',
);

$news_query = new WP_Query($news_args);

$count = 0;

if ($news_query->have_posts()) :
while ($news_query->have_posts()) : $news_query->the_post();

    if ( $count < 2 ) {
       //code to populate first two post
       $count++;
    }else
       //code to populate remaining posts
       $count++;
    }

endwhile;
```

Comment: It is displaying 2 posts per page

Comment: Nothing happened. I used bootstrap to make column grids. i unable to place your code with HTML tags. Have seen my entire code? Please help with this..

Answer (score 0):

Try to implement the following method.

```
$count = 0;

while (have_posts()) : the_post();

    if ( $count < 2 ) {
       //code to populate first two post
       $count++;
    }else
       //code to populate remaining posts
       $count++;
    }

endwhile;
```

Answer (score 0):

And finally i got the solution, placed if condition in columns dividing "div" tag.

Here is the final solution.

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
                <div class="row">
                <div class="ka-justcontent">
                 <?php
                $news_args = array(
                    'cat' => 3,
                    'paged' => get_query_var('paged'),
                    'posts_per_page' => 4,
                    'orderby' => 'post_date',
                    'order' => 'DESC',
                );
                $news_query = new WP_Query($news_args);
                $i = 0;
                if ($news_query->have_posts()) :
                while ($news_query->have_posts()) : $news_query->the_post();
                ?>
                            <div <?php if($i<2){?> class="col-md-12" <?php } else {?> class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6" <?php }?> >
                            <!-- Previous Next -->
                                <div class="survey">
                                <h3><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
                                    <p><span><?php the_time('F j, Y'); ?>
                                    </span>
                                    <span><?php echo "By: ".get_the_author(); ?>
                                    </span>
                                    <span>
                                    <?php
                                    $commentcount = comments_number('0', '1', '%');
                                    $fulltitle = $title . ' (' . $commentcount . ' comments)';
                                    ?>Comments<?php wp_count_comments( $post_id ); ?> 
                                    </span></p>
                                </div>
                                <figure class="fig_rel1">
                                <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
                                </figure>
                                <p>
                                <?php
                                $content = get_the_content('',FALSE,'');
                                $content = apply_filters('the_content', $content);
                                $content = str_replace(']]>', ']]>', $content);
                                echo substr($content,0,300).'<a href="'. get_permalink($post->ID) .'">Read More &raquo; </a>';
                                ?>
                                </p>
                            </div>
                <?php
                $i++;
                endwhile;
                previous_posts_link('prev', $news_query->max_num_pages);
                echo ' &mdash; ';
                next_posts_link('next', $news_query->max_num_pages);
                endif;
                ?>
                </div>
                </div>
                </div>              
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```